# Is there a clever HBase Schema to Aid with Discovering Missing Value?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, bigdata

Let's assume I have billions of rows in my HBase table.  The rows in this table change slowly, meaning there will be new rowkeys and some rowkeys get deleted.

I receive lots of events per row.  However, there will be **very few** rows that will not have any events associated with them.

At the end of the day I would like to report on the rows that have not received any events.

My naive solution would be to introduce a cf:c that holds a flag, set the flag to 1 every-time I see an event for it. Then do a full-scan of the table looking for rowkeys that are missing the column-value.  That seems like a waste, because I would be looking through 10 billion rows to discover a handful of rowkeys (we are talking about 100s or low 1000s).

Is there a clever way to design the hbase schema such that the rowkeys that are missing events could be found quickly (without going through every row)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have a rowkey xxxxyyyyzzzz1 ... xxxxyyyyzzzzn.
You have events for some rows and no events for other rows.
`c` is your flag to know whether events are there or not and you have huge data.

---

**Rule of thumb in HBase**: `RowFilter`s are always faster and more efficient than column value filters (for searching that flag, a full table scan is required).

Your approach to scan the entire table for missing events (column value filter) will lead to a full table scan and is not efficient.

**Conclusion**: You have to use a row key filter to scan such a big table.

So I'd suggest you write the flag in the row key. For example :

0 -- is for no events 
1 -- is there are events

xxxxyyyyzzzz1_0   // row with no events

xxxxyyyyzzzz1_1 // row with events

Now you can use a fuzzy row filter to capture missing event rows and take a report.

[Option 2  of your another question which was answered by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41873907/647053)

> Is there a clever HBase Schema to Aid with Discovering Missing Value?

From, my experience with hbase, there is no such thing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion...one question how do i change the rowkey when there is an event?  So do I start with row-key-0, when I get an event, delete row-key-0 and add row-key-1?

Comment: yes thats what I meant, 0 for no event 1 for event is present.Hope thats useful

Comment: Wouldn't mean billions of deletes on the table?  I don't think there is a way to update a rowkey?

Comment: ok i think you misunderstood me. while inserting the row (for first time) itself design rowkey in aforementioned way and later scan missing rows based on rowkey suffix.   "I don't think there is a way to update a rowkey?" Yes rowkeys cant be updated.

Comment: Hi we can have a chat to discuss in detail